# javascript couldn't apply index of on a string

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my code:

I take the value of a `td` like this:

```
$transactionIDFilterValue = $("#transactionIDFilter").val()
```

Then I compare it to another value like this:

```
function notGoodTransactionID(value, filterValue){
    index = 0;
    if (value.indexOf(filterValue) != -1) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

I am getting error that

> Uncaught TypeError: value.indexOf is not a function

Why is that?

Comment: What isn't working with your solution? Please show your efforts and add a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to your question.

Comment: This would only happen if value variable is undefined or null, please check it again, rather alert both the variable.

Comment: why all the downvotes? @Marco it seems there is a problem with your parameters. Are you sure they are strings?

Comment: Note, you can reduce your function to just `function notGoodTransactionID(value, filterValue)( return value.indexOf(filterValue) == -1; }`

Comment: where? i don't see something verifyable

Comment: @Michael reload the page, then

Comment: @Alex To see what's wrong and answer the question you need to debug the jsfiddle.  That alone makes it offtopic.  But `value` is being passed in as a jquery object, not a string.

Comment: Is it troll o clock? Back to the OP, try console.log your `$transactionIDFilterValue` and see if you have an undefined val

Comment: @JamesThorpe no you dont, the function is in the question. get your stuff together man!

Comment: @Alex really why this down votes ? ? ?

Comment: @Alex And how is the function being called?  The function itself is fine, it's the code around it that's the problem.

Comment: @JamesThorpe right, but that doesnt mean its OT or not proceedable without looking at the fiddle. kindly ask to add the missing information and youll be fine

Comment: @Alex Yes, it does.  There's a specific offtopic reason for this.

Comment: @JamesThorpe imagine there wasnt even a fiddle :)

Comment: @Alex Exactly - that would make it even more unanswerable as we wouldn't have a _clue_ what was going on.  That's why all the revelant information needs to be _in the question itself_.

Comment: @JamesThorpe you would know it depends on the parameters. just kindly ask the OP to provide that information - dont downvote directly! he made the effort of putting the function code which means he obviously doesnt know better - help him to do so!

Comment: @Alex I didn't downvote, but did vote to close, where [the consensus](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/256331/791010) is to do so immediately.  Feel free to vote to reopen if you truly believe this is a clear, answerable question with the information to hand.

Comment: @JamesThorpe I do so, too, generally. But in this case I didnt see it necessary.

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli you are calling all of your `notGood` functions every time the enter key is pressed. You need to selectively call the corresponding `notGood` function based on whether a value is present in each of the filter fields.

Comment: This question makes even less sense now you've removed the jsfiddle link - the accepted answer references code that's not even _linked_ from the question, never mind mentioned in the question itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `$transactionIDValue = $thisTR.find("td").eq(0);`, which you pass as first parameter, is not a string.

Change it to

```
$transactionIDValue = $.trim($thisTR.find("td").eq(0).text());
```

Comment: i wanted to get the value of the **first** td in that tr

Comment: use `$thisTR.find("td").eq(0).text()` then

Comment: @Igor maybe add `$.trim()`

Comment: @Alex - agree, added.

Answer (score 2):

This answer may not be correct, it depends what you're trying to get from a td.

I don't think that `.val()` is relevant for a td. If you are trying to find text, use `.text()`.

Here is a fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/1z9L18tL/

Comment: plus one, please remove the jsfiddle link, thanks for your understanding

Comment: May I ask why I should remove the fiddle? No problem with it but I'm new and like to understand these things

Comment: because it is something connected to my work, and it is not good to be public

Comment: Ah ok - no need to worry, if you check it out you'll see it's not at all related to your original fiddle, it's just a basic table to illustrate the point.